# Installing arabic language for magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to install Arabic Language for my store in magento. How can I do that?

When every time I click on arabic language pack in magento it only gives me `URL type text only`.

```
magento-community/Locale_Mage_community_ar_SA
```

I don't know how to do this?

and what to do with this `magento-community/Locale_Mage_community_ar_SA`?

Can anybody help? I mean step-by-step instruction or any `URL`.

Thanks

Comment: Is this the language pack you're working with? [Magento Community Modules - Arabic (Saudi Arabia) Language Pack](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Ahmed+J.+Hadi/extension/353/magento-community-modules--arabic-saudi-arabia-language-pack)

Comment: actually i am trying to install arabic language on my magento store and i dont know how to do this?

Comment: http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Locale_Mage_community_ar_SA

Answer (score 5):

From your console run:

```
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/ Locale_Mage_community_ar_SA
```

Answer (score 2):

- language  Package : 
  http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-community-modules-arabic-saudi-arabia-language-pack.html  get  key
- Admin panel ->system-> Magento Connect
   install  new language package
- admin panel-> system-> Configuration 
  -chose  you Current Configuration Scope
  -General -> Locale Options    set :Locale  Arabic (Saudi Arabia)  or  your  arabic package you chose (Egypt , Morocco ..etc)
- admin panel -> system -> Cache  Management : 
   Flush Magento Cache
- refresh  front page  for  your store

  **important notes :**
- by FtP  check language  check that folder : ar-SA  was exist  in following : path

  - [webroot]/app/locale
  - [webroot]/app/design/frontend/default/default/locale
  - [webroot]/app/design/frontend/default/modern/locale
    if  not  found  it  try  to upload it  manaul  for  offline  package : 
    http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations
- check  the code  for you arabic package  for  folder name : 
  ex : 
  Arabic (Saudi Arabia) | ar_SA
  Arabic (Morocco)      | ar_MA

Comment: JUST CHEKCING  IF  LANGUAGE FILE  IN FOLDER OR NOT  BY ftp PROGRAM